# How can i make this float formatting cleaner?

Tags: python, string, formatting, f-string

i am given a value e.g. $50.00. The output should be 50.0. Is there a way to make this cleaner? Especially my use of double float is bothering me

```
float(f"{float(d.removeprefix('$')):.1f}")
```

Comment: Depends what you need. For example if your string is '$50.99' your code may not produce the result you were expecting. No idea why you're calling float twice

Comment: when i didnt have the outer float, it returned me "50.0", so a string. I couldnt use that for multiplication afterwards, thus i wrapped it into another float(). You are right with your example...i didnt think about that as my code passed all the tests of my course. Suggestion on how you would solve that?

Comment: IMO Rounding a monetary amount looks like a snap decision. I would avoid that until the data is processed: `float(d.removeprefix('$'))`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're working with monetary amounts then this might give you more reliable results:

```
for d in '$50.99', '$50.00', '49.99':   
    print(float(f"{float(d.removeprefix('$')):.2f}"[:-1]))
```

Or...

```
for d in '$50.99', '$50.00', '49.99':   
    print(int(float(d.removeprefix('$'))*10)/10)
```

**Output:**

```
50.9
50.0
49.9
```

Comment: Thank you! your first solution seems to be best fitting to the courses needs. This way values like 50.99 dont get rounded to 51

Comment: @DimiTop Both solutions give the same results. The second option is significantly more efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can use round function to limit the result to one decimal.

```
round(float(d.removeprefix('$')), 1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.